# Do these tissues have 4 or 5 rabbinical certifications?

Tags: shabbat, kashrut-kosher, genizah-storage

In the image below:

1. Rabbinical ishur (certification) of the suitability of the facial tissues.
2. Certification that they are not made from recycled seforim (which probably means that the paper is non-recycled -- kind of the inverse of a "Green" certification.
3. Certification that they were not made on shabbos.
4. Certification of their suitability for use on  Pesach -- i.e., the tissues lack leavened bread or similar food substances..
5. Because #5 says "shvii", rather than not "shiviis", this is presumably also certification that they were not made on Shabbos, rather than certification concerning the sabbatical year. If so, why is this here, duplicating #3? And why do they say "shvii" (Seventh Day) rather than the more normal "Shabbos" (Sabbath)? If they feel that Shabbos is too holy to put on something that could be used for toiled paper, why does #3 explicitly say Shabbos?

(Aside: The Arabic text has more of the "normal"  explanation including size in centimeters and the material used; this is not in the Hebrew.)

[image: tissues]

Answer (score 1):

I think 1 and 4 are the same certification, viz that it's suitable for Passover. But that's not what you asked about.

I think 5 is the company's own say-so, and refers to an unspecified *ishur*, approval; 2 and 3 are then those approvals.